# "@arction/lcjs" Bug Report: Can't add a single slice to a pie chart with type "LabelsOnSides"

Tags: javascript, charts, lightningchart

as I said in the title, I can't create a pie chart with a single slice representing 100%, I just get the following exception.

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property 'nc' of undefined

You can reproduce this by going to the [interactive example](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0450-pieChart.html) and pasting in the following edited code that i used:

```
const lcjs = require('@arction/lcjs')
const { lightningChart, PieChartTypes } = lcjs

const pie = lightningChart().Pie({ type: PieChartTypes.LabelsOnSides });

pie.addSlice('test value', 100);
```

The strange thing is that if you change the type to **"LabelsInsideSlices"** it works fine, with no exceptions whatsoever.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the bug report. I have noted it down into our backlog. If I might inquire, how badly does this bug affect your usage of LightningChart?

Comment: @niilo-keinänen thanks, it isn't a huge issue, it's only mildly annoying because it often occures that we have a chart with only 1 value.

Comment: Hehe, I completely understand. We'll try to get the fix included in next release v.3.1 coming late this month. Happy coding~

Comment: While i'm here, to avoid opening another question, i'd like to suggest a feature for the pie chart that i noticed was missing (because i needed it).

There is no tooltip or click event on the slices, i had to get around it with the window mousedown event

Comment: Noted this feature request. Seems reasonable.

Comment: Update: the bug fix is ready and will be included in v.3.1

Comment: LightningChart JS v3.1.0 has been released. The release contains fix to this bug.